# Use Easily.Do offline?

Tags: offline

I installed Easily.Do on my android device, which is offline. But says I have to sign in. Is there a way to use EasilyDO without internet on my phone?

Comment: If you have to sign in then you'll need the Internet. You could ask the developer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to at least sign in once in the app, it cannot be used without connecting an account to it.

Now how much the app rely on online data to work, it's hard to tell without actually using it. So far, I've tried it and some informations like appointment and the weather are accessible (cached), but the app warns you that no data connection is available. Obviously, you won't receive any update while offline.